# Smart MySites(My Sites) 2010 Design for Page Real Estate

Tags: web-part, my-site, my-profile

Some Qustions about SP 2010 My Sites. We have a potential 20,000+ user farm. There are some very big groups that are interested in My Sites. These groups want to promote things on user mysites and some of their ideas might step on each other - and in some cases not work unless we can lock things down a bit.

1. With My sites in 2010 is it possible to limit/restrict/reserve areas of a mysite landing page for company wide promotions and notices?
2. Is it possible to make the mysites landing page dynamic based on information in a Users Profile or AD fields? And also keep users from changing these reserved areas of the MySite landing page?
3. In general is it possible and even a good idea for force how users can use their My Site? Can we force the landing page to look a certain way and even predetermine the webparts that will be availble. Possible to keep user from making any changes to main landing my site page at all?

Any suggestions and recommendations welcome.

Comment: This may help:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/customizing-mysite-template

Answer (score 0):

I just did a write up that would answer your questions and concerns.

[Customizing MySite template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/customizing-mysite-template)

The only one not directly answered was whether you could do a little magic based on user and/or group. We were goofing off one day and flipped styles per user in a proof of concept.

When you use a delegate control to inject css/scripts/controls etc you can just as easily use code behind to manipulate which controls are injected. You base that logic on the user who is viewing it. (Custom css with variable injection based on second letter of the last name anyone?)

The cool thing about delegate controls would be the ability to implement at any scope.
Even better, you can have a delegate control that is applied at the web app level then overridden at the site level, then overridden again at the web level in some instances.

I understand your concern about the 20k users, but in my experience of our 65k users only about 15k ever sign in, and very few are used consistently.

With 2013 they tried to make the mysite page a landing/home page for users. If you run that kind of structure of course you will have a lot more traffic.