# How to add Calendar to every "My Sites" Globally?

Tags: development, my-site, sharepoint-calendar, mysites

I want everyone in my company have their personal calendar in their SharePoint "My Site".
It means that I don't want to log in with everyone's credentials and go to their "my site" and add calendar App one by one. I want to manage a global My site template globally. Either with administration or development it's my critical need.

Anyone know how can I achieve this ?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: Do you want to add the new ones or the MySites already created?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I want to add something general in the current created My sites for every personnel in company.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out how to do this?

Comment: Not yet, I'm using powershell to loop through all my sites and add a calendar to each ! ... I'm not satisfied and yet I don't understand My Sites in depth

Answer (score 0):

MySites customizations can turn into a maintenance nightmare. Please be careful what you sign up for.
Check out how I have done them: [Customizing MySite template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/customizing-mysite-template)

I cover how you can do this both on the content side and on the template side.