# How to add List Template?

Tags: list-template

I just received a Document Library template from a vendor. I need to make this template automatically available when a user goes his/her my-site and create library.

Alternatively, i can have them download the stp from a location, upload it to list template and go that way. But I have 2000 users and each will use this template about 20 times to create 20 different document libraries based on this template.

I dont have the time to create custom site template for my-site so I can built into that. so that option is not on the table. My-site is barely got activated in our environment so I can't just have a powershell to do that.

What other option I have to make sure the custom list template shows up in the library template choices when user wants to create a library based on this template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option A: Create a site template and have that list already created from that list template, so that way whenever users create the site, the list is already there waiting for them.

Option B: Upload the list template to the gallery, and give users the option to manually create the list after site creation.

EDIT: Whenever the user creates their site, they will have a list of templates that they can create. Just inform the users that they must create the site from the site template you created. Or, optionally, you can restrict the access to just that site template. You need to create the site, use the list template provided, then save the site as a template (lets say its named "New Site Template"). Tell the end-users to use that site template "New Site Template" instead.

Comment: If I create a site template then How do I tell sharePOint that whenever user create his/her site or activate his/her my-site then use the new site template.

Comment: please see my edit.

Comment: When user clicks on My Content from mysite link it automatically creates my site collection for that user and does not provide user with the option to select site template.

Comment: MySites are a completely different animal. It's very tricky, but it can be done through delegate controls: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/customizing-mysite-template